# Using a variable with currentTarget

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Hi I have just posted something simalar but i have not explained it very well. I want a to control the alpha of a movieclip when the mouse is over it . This works fine where 'wedding' is the movie clip .

```
  wedding.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, pan_over) ;



function pan_over(event:MouseEvent):void{
  var ct:String = event.currentTarget.name ; 

  TweenLite.to(wedding, 1, { alpha:0  }); 
 }
```

What I want to do is use a variable instead of hard coding the word wedding like the example below. But it does not work

```
wedding.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, pan_over) ;
 }


 function pan_over(event:MouseEvent):void{
  var ct:String = event.currentTarget.name ; 

  TweenLite.to(ct, 1, { alpha:0  });
 }
```

Do I need to declare CT as somwthing other than a string ? . could anyone help please ?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not Tween a String! Stand back and look at your code for a bit. at the moment your example is trying to tween the alpha of the "name" of your Movieclip. What you actually want to do, is tween the alpha property of your Movieclip.

[event.currentTarget](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/events/Event.html#currentTarget) is a [DisplayObject](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html) so you can just use it, even without declaring a variable. Like this...

```
function pan_over(event:MouseEvent):void 
{
    TweenLite.to(event.currentTarget, 1, { alpha:0 }); 
}
```

To set the currentTarget to a movieClip variable just do this inside you event handler:

```
var cTarget:MovieClip = e.currentTarget as MovieClip;
```